# Tallying columns using Countif with a variable number of rows

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, countif

I'm using Google Sheets for a spreadsheet I'm working on.

Basically, I'm counting the number of times some different items (items are all listed in columns) live inside of different application windows (all my windows are listed in rows).

I'm just plopping a checkmark to say yes when an item lives in a window.

I want to tally this, and I'm using Countif like this: =countif(C4:C38,"✔")

However, if I find a new item, or window, everything has to move and I have to update the formula's column or row number.

Is there a way to make the Countif's range dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

To count the checkmarks in column C, irrespective of how many rows are in the sheet:

`=COUNTIF(C:C,"✔")`

To count the checkmarks from the fourth row down in column C, and not be affected by row insertion/deletion:

`=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("C4:C"),"✔")`

To count the checkmarks from the fourth row in column C, down to the row above where the formula is placed:

`=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("C4:C"&(ROW()-1)),"✔")`

Comment: Ah I see. As you say, might need to wait for an example.

Comment: This didn't work. I got the message: "Error
Circular dependency detected.”

As far as an example, in my example above, where I have 38 rows being counted, if I add some new rows past 38 and put checkmarks in them, they won’t be counted.

I don’t know the syntax and can’t find it, but would have expected something like @AdamL suggested.

Comment: In what cell are you wanting the formula?

Comment: All cells in a row, or all cells in a column. I want to be able to add new rows in between existing ones and have =Countif update to include them all.

Comment: Yes, but where do you specifically want the COUNTIF result to go? In column C, if the current data is in C4:C38, where will the result be? C39? C1? Again, feel free to share an example.

Comment: In your example, I want the result to end up in C39, *unless* I add a new row. In that case, I want the results to land on C40 and *include* data from the new row.